# Android: What do the parameters in InputFilter.filter mean and when is filter actually called?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I am trying to understand the six parameters in the InputFilter.filter() method, so I have written the following class.

```
final class MyFilter implements InputFilter {

static final String TAG = "MyFilter";

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    Log.d(TAG, "source = \"" + source + "\"");
    Log.d(TAG, "start = " + start);
    Log.d(TAG, "end = " + end);
    Log.d(TAG, "dest = \"" + dest + "\"");
    Log.d(TAG, "dstart = " + dstart);
    Log.d(TAG, "dend = " + dend);
    return null;
}}
```

I have included an EditText in my activity and written:

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new MyFilter() });
```

When I modify the text in the EditText I get some results I can't understand at all.

When I write "a", filter() is called once with parameters "a", 0, 1, "", 0, 0.

When I add 'b' so it says "ab", filter() is called twice, first with the parameters
"ab", 0, 2, "a", 0, 1 and then with the parameters "ab", 0, 2, "ab", 0, 2.

When I add 'c' so it says "abc", filter() is called only once with parameters "abc", 0, 3, "ab", 0, 2.

When I add 'd' so it says "abcd", filter() is called twice, the first time with parameters "abcd", 0, 4, "abc", 0, 3 and then with parameters "abcd", 0, 4, "abcd", 0, 4.

When I add subsequent characters, filter() is only called once for each.

What is going on? Why are strings of length 2 and 4 treated differently to strings of length 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8...?

Also why are there 6 parameters, when 2 seems to be enough?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain this.

Comment: Did you check [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html)?

Comment: I did. It didn't help.

Comment: `This method is called when the buffer is going to replace the range dstart … dend of dest with the new text from the range start … end of source. Return the CharSequence that you would like to have placed there instead, including an empty string if appropriate, or null to accept the original replacement. Be careful to not to reject 0-length replacements, as this is what happens when you delete text. Also beware that you should not attempt to make any changes to dest from this method; you may only examine it for context.` It explains what each of the 6 parameters is for.

Comment: Can you explain why strings of length 3 are treated differently to strings of length 2 and 4?

Comment: You could compare the spans of the source/dest values for the filter() callback when the source and dest strings appear to be the same. It could be another InputFilter or TextWatcher triggering changes.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. There's definitely something odd going on here as I get completely different results depending on the device I use. I'd be really grateful if someone could explain when the filter() method is supposed to get called as you add letters to the EditText, and what the parameters should be, so at least I know which device is giving the correct results.

Comment: It could even be the keyboard triggering other events (which can definitely differ between devices). While your results are inconsistent, they don't invalidate the method contract. There's nothing that states it will only be called once per key event.